# Inflating WebView is slow since Lollipop

Tags: java, android, performance, webview

In fact I am surprised that I found no similar question in Stackoverflow, but I really can't figure it out.

**First of all, please be reminded that this is not related to the performance of browsing webpage inside a WebView. It is only about inflating even an empty WebView, without loading any URL.**

To eliminate all other factors, I have created a brand new project which contains things only necessary to reproduce the problem.

In this almost empty project, I have a layout which contains only a `WebView`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.testing.WebViewOnlyActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

And I have a `MainActivity` which contains only a `Button` which starts this `WebViewOnlyActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebViewOnlyActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Simple enough, right?

Now, when I build the project, click the button, the `WebViewOnlyActivity` takes **more than 1 second to popup**. But then if I press back button, and press the button again, the `WebViewOnlyActivity` appears immediately. **Apparently Android cached something of WebView**.

Here are my testing devices:
1. Android 7.1.1: Slow
2. Android 7.0.0: Slow
3. Android 5.0.2 Slow
4. Android 4.4.1 Fast

So it appears to me this only happens since Lollipop.

However, such 1.x second delay is still unacceptable to me. Does anyone knows how to solve it? (Well, I think it is hard because I did nothing to this WebView... May be I should use some 3rd party WebView?)

P.S. I have also used traceview to see what are the differences between a 7.1.1 device and 4.4.1 Device. It is clear that `WebView's` `init()` method is taking up a lot of time.

7.1.1:
[image: 7.1.1 Trace View]
And further deeper:
[image: 7.1.1 Deeper]

4.4.1:
[image: 4.4.1 Trace View]
And further deeper:
[image: 4.4.1 Deeper]

Big Difference!

---

Although it is really empty, but requested by Axel, I will post the code for WebViewOnlyActivity as well:

```
public class WebViewOnlyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view_only);

    }
}
```

---

Comment: Android 4.4 started to use Chromium as rendering engine https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html Then, Android 7.0 switched to multiprocess WebView by default https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#webview So, I cannot explain why you see the change from 4.4 to 5.0. That being said, in your screenshot I see 200ms... where are the 800+ms to get to 1s are?

Comment: Does the delay disappear if there is no webview inside your layout?

Comment: @AxelD. Yes. It will appear immediately.

Comment: @XavierRubioJansana In fact, even if I kill the app and restart, the webview is a bit faster than a fresh start. I think that is because Android cached some resources of WebView needed in memory, where killing the app will not remove those caches. For example, if I opened a WebView in app A, it will also speeds up opening WebView in app B. But I think the significant difference shown above is enough to demonstrate the problem, so I didn't mention it

Comment: I don't know how to fix it, it looks like an OS issue, but I can suggest two possible workarounds. First, you could create a hidden `WebView` in a previous `Activity` by code, at an adequate moment (for example, after `onStart`), and then destroy it. This would "prime" the OS cache. Another option would be to replace the `WebView` with a `ViewStub` to lazily load the `WebView` after the `onStart`. The user will see the `Activity` very quickly, and then the `WebView` will load.

Comment: @XavierRubioJansana I tried AsyncLayoutInflator but it will crash, didn't think of these 2 methods you have mentioned. I will give it a try, thanks so much!

Comment: Sorry guys...but i have been working now for years with Android and especially with WebViews. Never recognized such a delay. Please show the code of WebViewOnlyActivity.class

Comment: @AxelD. it is really empty. But I updated the post anyway.

Comment: @Sira Lam and what about inflating the webview at runtime?

Comment: @XavierRubioJansana I tried ViewStub, but even if I put it in `onResume`, it is still taking up the activity creation time. However, if I use an `Handler` plus `postDelayed`, the activity appears immediately. Thank you so much!

Comment: I can confirm this. When trying to improve my app startup duration I found that a simple (even empty) webview in the XML adds 300ms to my layout inflation >< ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT 2017-12-21**

I even created a library to tackle this problem easily.
You may download it [here](https://github.com/siralam/WebViewSuite/).
Give it a star if you find it useful :P

---

Thanks to @XavierRubioJansana 's hint, I tried [ViewStub](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html) to delay the inflation.

However, even if I delay the inflation to `onResume()`, it will still slows the activity creation.

But then if I use a `Handler` to `postDelay` the inflation, activity creates immediately!

```
    Handler webViewInflateHandler = new Handler();
    webViewInflateHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!webViewInflated) {
                webView = (WebView) webViewStub.inflate();
                webViewInflated = true;
            }
        }
    }, 50);
```

Then, you need to delay all kinds of setup and loading of `WebView` until it is inflated. I will suggest using RxJava here to observe an `BehaviorSubject<Boolean>`.